# Find the remainder when $5^{2001} + (27)!$ is divided by 8

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$5^{2001} + (27)!$ is divided by 8. Could someone please help me solve this. 
I managed to show that $5^{2001} \equiv 13(mod8)$ but now I am stuck and don't know what to do to show the remainder when it is $27!$

Comment: $27! = 1\times2\times\cdots \times 8\times \cdots \times 27$

Comment: I still need more help, I don't know how to use that to find the remainder

Comment: If $27!$ is a multiple of $8$, then what is $27!\mod 8$?

Comment: 27! is congruent to 0 mod(8). Is that correct?

Comment: Yup!  So what does that tell you about $5^{2001} + 27!\mod 8$?  (Remember that $13 \equiv 5 \mod 8$)

Answer (score 2):

> $$(\text{mod}\ 8)$$

$$5^2\equiv25\equiv8\cdot 3+1\equiv1$$

Then $$5^{2001}\equiv(5^2)^{1000}\cdot 5\equiv1\cdot 5=5$$

Since $27!$ is multiple of $8$ we get $$5^{2001}+27!\equiv5+0\equiv5.$$

Comment: so is the remainder 5? I am still a little confused?

Comment: @marcus Yes, $0\leq 5<8$ and $5^{2001}+27!\equiv 5(\text{mod}\ 8)$.